# Google Web App to Hide my private Information

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Summary: Can a web app call UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) for me, but add a private key to the url?

I extract information from a server which requests an API key. The service requires that my API key stays hidden, but I want to create Google Sheets that can be used by anyone.  Currently in Google Sheets I don't see a way to keep the key hidden, as the whole spreadsheet is clientside.

Can a web-app do this, but keep the key hidden (so if they explore the page source, they still won't see it)? So essentially in my spreadsheet I'll call:
UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://mywebapp.com/getdata?myservice.com/requests")
 and then the web app calls:
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://myservice.com/requests?" + privatekey)
and my spreadsheet users have no idea what the value of private key is?

Answer (score 2):

yea its possible but with workarrounds. the other answer already tells you that the .gs code can be viewed. there are a few ways you can hide the special value:
1) you could keep it on another private spreadsheet, and have the code read it from there. as long as you make the code run as yourself, others wont be able to view the value.
2) make a standalone webapp, not as part of the sheet and do everything from the webapp. share the published webapp url only.
from your question, its not clear how you are calling the fetch (from a custom function? menu item? onEdit?"etc) which is very relevant here. also not clear why you give a custom url to an apps script webapp (its not possible) but in any case both these methods should help you.

Comment: I call it from a custom function which retrieves a JSON stringified string, which I then convert to ranges etc. I am happy with keeping it in a private spreadsheet, and to let all the API calls come "via" me.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to create a Library. Then to add the library to your references. For safety's sake I added the key to the "Properties Service" but it seems it's not necessary.  (I logged into a different google account and could not explore the library calls even through debug mode).

My eventual RemoteRequest library code:

```
function GetRequestWithAPIKey(url) {
  alldata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + apikey()).getContentText();
  return alldata;
}

function apikey_() {  // The _ at the end makes this private
// Get multiple script properties in one call, then log them all.
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var data = scriptProperties.getProperties();
  s = "";
  for (var key in data) {
    s = s + data[key];
  }
  return s;
}
```

I really struggled to get the PropertiesService to get my key, so I just got all keys knowing I only have 1.